# Extract HTML table with superscripts using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, superscript

I am trying to extract the table at [this webpage](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/index.php?set=2) using R, with the following code:

```
library('htmltab')
url <- "http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/index.php?set=2"
app.data<- htmltab(url, which = 3, rm_superscript = F, rm_whitespace=F, rm_invisible=F)
```

However, the superscripts are then integrated into the main text, so an entry in the table like 3^{10}109 outputs as 310109, which is clearly not the same thing. If one sets `rm_superscript = T`, then the output is e.g. 3109, i.e. the superscripts are then absent entirely, which is also not right. What I'd like is the superscripts clearly indicated, so an output like 3^{10}109. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate approach.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/index.php?set=2"

pg <- read_html(URL)
```

extract the table and convert it back to raw HTML

```
tab <- as.character(html_nodes(pg, "table")[[3]])
```

manually replace the `<sup></sup>` with `{}`, convert it back and extract the table

```
dat <- html_table(read_html(gsub("</sup>", "}", gsub("<sup>", "{", tab) )))[[1]]

head(dat)
##     quality  size merit       by       on       a            b             c
## 1 1  1.6299  6.81  8.64       ER 19870101       2     3{10}​109         23{5}
## 2 2  1.6260  7.68 10.18      BdW 19850920   11{2} 3{2}​5{6}​7{3}       2{21}​23
## 3 3  1.6235 15.70 26.86    JB JB 19940401 19·​1307 7·​29{2}​31{8} 2{8}​3{22}​5{4}
## 4 4  1.5808  9.92 13.01 JB JB AN 19930312     283   5{11}​13{2} 2{8}​3{8}​17{3}
## 5 5  1.5679  3.64  2.89      BdW 19880106       1       2·​3{7}         5{4}​7
## 6 6  1.5471  4.77  4.17      BdW 19880106    7{3}        3{10}       2{11}​29
```